# Import Visual Basic text inputs into Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, ms-office

So I have the visual basic side of it all covered with the input stuff and dims all written by me and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` stuff added from a Microsoft VB reference. The VB has no errors but I still cannot figure out how to get the inputs put into the `oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = txtCustomer.Text` input to go to Excel. I do not see any option to add the Excel spreadsheet to VB. I tried going through Excel Developer mode to import VB code but it would not let me save my VB code properly so I would rather keep the VB where it is. Here is the VB code

````
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub BtnCalc_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click

        Dim stringDate As String
        Dim house, roof, paver, drive As Integer
        Dim dblhouse, dblroof, dblpaver, dbldrive As Double
        Dim dbllocale As Double
        Dim tax As Integer
        Dim customer As String

        customer = txtCustomer.Text
        stringDate = TxtDate.Text
        Dim LstSize As String
        Dim dbltotal As Double
        Dim location As Integer

        '''house sizes

        If location = "1800" Then
            dbllocale = 1.0
        End If

        If location = "2400" Then
            dbllocale = 1.2
        End If

        If location = "3000" Then
            dbllocale = 1.65
        End If

        If location = "4000" Then
            dbllocale = 2.2
        End If

        ''checks for which parts of the house get power washed
        If ChkCredit.Checked = True Then
            tax = 1.07
        Else
            tax = 1
        End If

        ''check for house
        If Chkhouse.Checked = True Then
            house = 1
        Else
            house = 0
        End If

        ''check for roof
        If ChkRoof.Checked = True Then
            roof = 1
        Else
            roof = 0
        End If

        ''check for pavers/sidewalks
        If ChkPaver.Checked = True Then
            paver = 1
        Else
            paver = 0
        End If

        ''check for driveways/large patios
        If ChkDrive.Checked = True Then
            drive = 1
        Else
            drive = 0
        End If

        dblhouse = (house * 350.0) * (dbllocale)
        dblroof = (roof * 450.0) * (dbllocale)
        dblpaver = (paver * 125.0)
        dbldrive = (drive * 165.0)
        dbltotal = tax * ((dblhouse) + (dblroof) + (dblpaver) + (dbldrive))
        TxtTotal.Text = (dbltotal)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LstSize.SelectedIndexChanged
        Location = LstSize.SelectedItem
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
        'closes application
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
        txtCustomer.Text = ""
        Chkhouse.Checked = False
        ChkRoof.Checked = False
        ChkPaver.Checked = False
        ChkDrive.Checked = False
        TxtTotal.Text = ""
        ChkCredit.Checked = False
        'clears text boxes and total text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Try

            Dim oXL As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
            Dim oWB As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
            Dim oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
            Dim oRng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range


            'On Error GoTo Err_Handler
            ' Start Excel and get Application object.
            oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oXL.Visible = True

            ' Get a new workbook.
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
            oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet

            ' Add cells by looping.
            Dim iRow As Integer = 1
            For iRow = 1 To 10
                oSheet.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = "Test" & iRow
            Next iRow

            '//Create an Array and then add these entries to an excel spreadsheet
            Dim a(10) As String
            For iRow = 1 To 10
                a(iRow) = "Array Entry" & iRow.ToString
            Next

            '//Add to sheet
            For iRow = 1 To 10
                oSheet.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = a(iRow)
            Next iRow

            '//Add from a textbox Control
            oSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = txtCustomer.Text

            ' Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
            ' of Microsoft Excel's lifetime.
            oXL.Visible = True
            oXL.UserControl = True

            ' Make sure you release object references.
            oRng = Nothing
            oSheet = Nothing
            oWB = Nothing
            oXL = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class```
````

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Do you get an error?  If Yes, where is the error and what's the error message?

Comment: Just starting at the top, location can never equal "1800" because you have declared location as an Integer and "1800" is a String. In any event location will always = 0 because you have not made any assignment to it.

Comment: There is no error as it is not fully set up, you can see there is an excel filepath spreadsheet assigned in the VB code but the spreadsheet never updates, so I am not sure if the VB is wrong or if there is something to be done in Excel to enable it being updated by VB.

Comment: "you can see there is an excel filepath spreadsheet assigned" No, I do not see that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Most of your variable names are good but why call the house size `location`? How about `houseSize`?

In addition to my comment, use a `Select Case` so the code does not have to evaluate each If statement. `Select Case` stops when it finds a match.

`CheckBox.Checked` is a boolean. If a property of method returns a `Boolean` it is not necessary to use `= True`. It will not give an error but it extra typing.

`tax` cannot equal 1.07. 1.07 is a double and cannot be directly assigned to an Integer. I have changed tax to a `Decimal`. I have changed all the `Doubles` to `Decimal` as this is better when working with money. The D following the literal number tells the compiler that this is a decimal.

Remember the Associative property of multiplication from Algebra? It works in vb.net so you can rid of some of the parenthesis.

```
Private Sub BtnCalc_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click
    Dim house, roof, paver, drive As Integer
    Dim dblhouse, dblroof, dblpaver, dbldrive As Decimal
    Dim dbllocale As Decimal
    Dim tax As Decimal
    Dim dbltotal As Decimal
    Dim houseSize As Integer = CInt(LstSize.SelectedItem) '**EDIT**
    Dim customer = txtCustomer.Text
    Dim stringDate = TxtDate.Text
    'house sizes
    Select Case houseSize
        Case 1800
            dbllocale = 1D
        Case 2400
            dbllocale = 1.2D
        Case 3000
            dbllocale = 1.65D
        Case 4000
            dbllocale = 2.2D
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show($"No matching location. Location = {houseSize}")
            Return
    End Select
    ''checks for which parts of the house get power washed
    If ChkCredit.Checked Then
        tax = 1.07D
    Else
        tax = 1
    End If
    ''check for house
    If Chkhouse.Checked Then
        house = 1
    End If
    ''check for roof
    If ChkRoof.Checked Then
        roof = 1
    End If
    ''check for pavers/sidewalks
    If ChkPaver.Checked Then
        paver = 1
    End If
    ''check for driveways/large patios
    If ChkDrive.Checked Then
        drive = 1
    End If

    dblhouse = house * 350 * dbllocale
    dblroof = roof * 450 * dbllocale
    dblpaver = paver * 125
    dbldrive = drive * 165
    dbltotal = tax * (dblhouse + dblroof + dblpaver + dbldrive)
    TxtTotal.Text = dbltotal.ToString
End Sub
```

This `Location = LstSize.SelectedItem` will not compile because Location is not declared. If you want to get the value from a list box do it directly in the `Btn_click` event.

As to the completely unrelated Excel code...
At the top of your file `Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` This saves you some typing because you can use Exce instead of `Microsoft blah blah` blah

```
Private Sub TestExcel()
    Dim oXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    oXL.Visible = True
    ' Get a new workbook.
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
    'Add a sheet
    oSheet = CType(oWB.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
    ' Add data by looping.
    For iRow = 1 To 10
        oSheet.Range("A" & iRow).Value = "Test" & iRow
    Next
    'Create an Array and then add these entries to an excel spreadsheet
    Dim a(9) As String 'an array in vb.net is declared with the upper bound in the parenthesis
    For iRow = 1 To 10
        a(iRow - 1) = "Array Entry" & iRow.ToString
    Next

    For iRow = 0 To 9 'indexes in arrays start at zero
        oSheet.Range("B" & (iRow + 1)).Value = a(iRow)
    Next

    'Add from a textbox Control                                                                                                      left, top, width, height
    Dim ExcelTextBox As Excel.Shape = oSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 200, 100, 200, 50)
    ExcelTextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Insert TextBox in Excel"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much better, however I cannot seem to get the lstbox ``houseSize = LstSize.SelectedItem`` working... it either has a syntax error if declared or shows as the else option when i leave just the case housesize. I also like the excel stuff but am not sure how it works, is it sending results to a designated file?

Comment: See my edit to my to the Button click. If you run the Excel code you can see what it does.

Comment: Yea I tried doing a convert just like the edit and it doesnt change it, it comes up as the else no matter what. If i comment out the else result in the select case it defaults everything and doesnt use the dbllocale multiplier to multiply the price by the house size. I am not able to see what the excel does yet but I'm guessing it makes a new workbook, but I do not see which vars it will actually add to the excel textbox... ideally it prints each result of the txt.customer.text to a row

Comment: I have since removed all of the dbllocale and location vars and simplified it that is only the house/ roof checks, name, credit, and calender. The program now prints the right response every time, however I still have not seen any excel results.